# CURL and Pregmatch a specefic file address

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to curl a URL and the result is this :

Curl command in PHP :

```
$url = "https://example.com/api/v1/report_creator/generate.pdf";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Output :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var timeout = 1000;
      var checkReport = function() {
        $.getJSON("b15a02aa-182d.json")
       .fail(function() {
          setTimeout(checkReport, timeout);
        });
      };
      checkReport();
    });
  </script>
```

Now i need to fin the json file :
b15a02aa-182d.json

So I tried to do :

```
preg_match_all("/$.getJSON(\"(.*)\")/", $result, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

But wasn't able to extract the json address

Comment: You neglected to escape all those characters that have special meaning in regex here - the `$`, the `.`, the `(` and `)` that are supposed to be meant literal …

Comment: Any reply to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3754125/144421), Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've neglected to escape the special characters in the Regex pattern. Certain characters do specific things in Regex. From your pattern there's:

- `$` which matches the end of the string
- `.` which matches any character, used correctly in your capture group
- `(` and `)` which denote a group, again used correctly elsewhere

These characters all need to be escaped to match the actual character, rather than do the special thing they represent. Escape them the same way you did with the `"` character and it works.

```
preg_match_all("/\$\.getJSON\(\"(.*)\"\)/", $result, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```